# How to save data in to cache come from rest API with Axios in Vue 3 with option API

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

How to avoid duplicate API requests in Vue 3 with option Api. That means cache the data in the browser when first visited the API

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage?retiredLocale=de), it allows you to store data in the browser (only strings, but `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are your friend) over multiple sessions. You do have direct access to the `window.localStorage`-object in every browser environment (*not* NodeJS), so it can totally be used with front-end frameworks like `vue.js`.

You can find a very minimal example at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-spence-ifps9z?file=/src/App.vue):

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("result")) {
  this.result = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("result"));
} else {
  const data = fetch("YOUR_URL").then(async (res) => {
    const json = await res.json();
    localStorage.setItem("result", JSON.stringify(json));
    this.result = json;
  });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to share any live example code as like codesandbox.io or jsfiddle.net any github repo ?